# Apache Camel bean parameter binding issue with Spring DSL

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

I am running into a strange issue with Apache Camel and Spring DSL. Here is an excerpt of my Spring defined route:

```
<route>
  <from uri="direct:process-xml"/>
  <setHeader headerName="documentRootOid">
    <method bean="foo.bar.util.TranslatorUtil" method="extractDocumentRootOid"/>
  </setHeader>
  <setHeader headerName="organization">
    <method bean="foo.bar.util.OrgServices" method="getOrganizationByOid(*,${header.documentRootOid})"/>
  </setHeader>
  <setHeader headerName="organizationStyleSheet">
    <method bean="foo.bar.util.TranslatorUtil" method="extractStyleSheetAttributeFromOrganization(*,${header.organization})"/>
  </setHeader>
  <bean beanType="foo.bar.util.Utils" method="transformBodyUsingStyleSheet(*,${header.organizationStyleSheet}"/>
....
</route>
```

Everything works fine up until the last line that I posted. The `extractDocumentRootOid(Exchange exchange)` java method is executed and the result is stored to the **documentRootOid** header.

The `getOrganizationByOid(Exchange exchange, String oid)` java method is executed and the result is stored to the **organization** header.

The `extractStyleSheetAttributeFromOrganization(Exchange exchange, Organization organization)` java method is executed and the result is stored to the **organizationStyleSheet** header.

Once it gets to the `transformBodyUsingStyleSheet` method, things get weird. Here is my method declaration:

```
public void transformBodyUsingStyleSheet(Exchange exchange, String styleSheet)
```

I put a debugger on the first line of the method and the `styleSheet` value always appears to be the exchange body, NOT the value that I am trying to pass in `(${header.organizationStyleSheet})`.

If I look at the headers through a debugger, I see my **organizationStyleSheet** header and the value that I expect, so I am guessing that there is an issue with my bean parameter bindings? Has anyone else ran into this before?

P.S. I tried replacing `*` with `${exchange}` but got a number of errors saying

```
org.apache.camel.ExpressionEvaluationException: 
  Cannot create/evaluate simple expression: 
    ${exchange} to be bound to parameter at index: 0 on method"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this was caused by a missing closing parenthesis on the "transformBodyUsingStyleSheet" method.  I fixed that and it resolved my issue.

Comment: This happened to me to and I have spent a couple of hours trying to debug this issue. Maybe should we ask mister Claus Ibsen if the parser of the expression for binding the beans should fail in this case ?

Comment: @BalabanMario log a bug with the camel project then. No need to ask.